# Changing the order of limits when calculating a limiting probability using conditional probability

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be random variables defined on the space $\Omega_n$, for all $n\geq 1$. Assume further that $Y_n \sim Bin(n,\frac{1}{2})$, so in particular, $$E(Y_n)=\frac{n}{2},$$ and $$Var(Y_n)=\frac{n}{4}.$$

I'd like to calculate the limiting probability
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n \in A)$$
and do that using conditioning on $Y_n$:
$$ P(X_n \in A) = \sum_{k=0}^n P(X_n \in A\,|\,Y_n = k) \cdot P(Y_n = k).$$
Moreover, it's convenient in my case to let $k$ assume values within $C$ standard deviations from the mean, i.e.
$$ \underbrace{P(X_n \in A)}_{a_n} = \underbrace{\sum_{k\in \mathbb{N}\cap[\frac{n}{2} - C \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2},\frac{n}{2} + C \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}]} P(X_n \in A\,|\,Y_n = k) \cdot P(Y_n = k)}_{a_{n,C}},$$
then take the limit $n\to\infty$, and finally take the limit $C\to\infty$.

**Question:** How to propely justify the equality
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{C\to\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,C}$$